# "Import Error: DLL load failed" while converting ".py file" (having "import rasterio") to ".exe file" using pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, rasterio

I have a python (version `3.7`) file named `test.py` which I want to convert to `test.exe` using `pyinstaller`. When I am using the command

```py
pyinstaller test.py
```

it is creating `test.exe` successfully. But when I am trying to execute the `test.exe` file using command prompt I am getting following error:

```py
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\users\user1\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\rasterio\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[460] Failed to execute script test"
```

After going through similar post in the website, I tried different options like:

(i) First option: In the path `C:\Users\user1\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks` I have added a `hook-rasterio.py` containing `hiddenimports=['rasterio', 'rasterio._shim']` and then tried

```py
pyinstaller -F test.py
```

but still I am getting the above error.

(ii) Second option: Inside the `test.spec` file in `hiddenimports=[]` I added `rasterio` and `rasterio._shim` and then created `test.exe` using `pyinstaller` but still the issue persists.

My `test.py` looks like:

```py
import rasterio
print("It's Done....")
```

Can anyone suggest necessary things which could be done in resolving the issue.

Answer (score 2):

`rasterio` is a complex library and it depends on many external libraries. Your error is a DLL load error which means that it lacks some DLL files required by the `rasterio`. I suggest you follow the installation process in [here](https://github.com/conda-forge/rasterio-feedstock#installing-rasterio) and make sure that you are installed `rasterio` correctly with your conda environment (use a new env for this).

Next, check that `rasterio` is imported without any problem with something like:

```
import traceback
try:
    import rasterio
    print("Import OK!")
except ImportError:
    print("Import Error!")
    traceback.print_exc()
input()
```

Next, install PyInstaller and use below spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['test.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\Masoud\\Desktop\\test'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
a.datas += Tree('C:\\Users\\Masoud\\Anaconda3\\envs\\testEnv\\Lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\', prefix='rasterio')
a.datas += Tree('C:\\Users\\Masoud\\Anaconda3\\envs\\testEnv\\Lib\\xml', prefix='xml')
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='test',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=False,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )
```

In the above script, I'm bringing the whole `rasterio` and `xml` libraries beside to executable, as PyInstaller can't resolve the module import. Remember to change the paths according to your setup.

Finally, generate your executable with:

```
pyinstaller test.spec
```

Comment: Hi Masoud.Thanks for the reply. I wanted to inform you that "import rasterio" is working fine in my python environment.I would like to confirm from you that whether path to "rasterio & xml" should be "C:\\Users\\user1\\Anaconda3\\envs\\test\\Lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\" & "C:\\Users\\user1\\Anaconda3\\envs\\test\\Lib\\xml", as in my case rasterio folder doesn't exists in the above mentioned path while for xml it is.In my case rasterio is present in "C:\\Users\\user1\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\" and xml also exists in "C:\\Users\\ashish\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\xml".

Comment: Also when I am using this new path in the above spec file and then use pyinstaller to generate exe, issue is still there. So you can kindly confirm and suggest.

Comment: You need to replace three paths: 1. two `Tree` path for xml and rasterio as you mentioned. 2. `pathex` which is the root path of your project. Remember that I installed the latest version of rasterio from the above link.

Comment: For pathex I have used 'C:\\Users\\user1\\Desktop\\New folder\\test\\'. Whereas for rasterio I have used "C:\\Users\\user1\\Anaconda3\\envs\\test\\Lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\" and for xml I have used "C:\\Users\\user1\\Anaconda3\\envs\\test\\Lib\\xml" and then used "pyinstaller test.spec" but still after running the exe file from command prompt I am getting same error "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[460] Failed to execute script test"

Comment: It is ok when you first-time run `pyinstaller test.py -F --noupx` it would generate spec file. So you just need to add two `a.datas +=` to spec file and run `pyinstaller test.spec`.

Comment: Hi Masoud. I tried 'pyinstaller test.py -F --noupx' which created a 'test.spec' file. In this I have added two 'a.datas +=' i.e. a.datas += Tree('C:\\Users\\user1\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\', prefix='rasterio') and a.datas += Tree('C:\\Users\\user1\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\xml', prefix='xml') and then run 'pyinstaller test.spec' which created a 'test.exe' file inside 'dist' folder. But when I am running this file through cmd prompt I am getting same error i.e. 'DLL failed error'.

Comment: Create a new env with conda, activate it, then install `rasterio` and `pyinstaller`. On the env try to generate your executable as you do.

Comment: Adding these two lines to the spec file:
a.datas += Tree('C:\\Users\\Masoud\\Anaconda3\\envs\\testEnv\\Lib\\site-packages\\rasterio\\', prefix='rasterio')
a.datas += Tree('C:\\Users\\Masoud\\Anaconda3\\envs\\testEnv\\Lib\\xml', prefix='xml')

and two other files to the working directory solved my problems, thanks!

Comment: Anyone who installed Chris Gohlke's rasterio wheel files will also need to add `a.datas += Tree('C:\\Users\\Masoud\\Anaconda3\\envs\\testEnv\\Lib\\site-packages\\osgeo\\` to their spec file.